# Should I use camelCase to abide by pep-8 line length?

Tags: python

I've started following PEP-8 strictly, because I thought I should at least try it before just picking and choosing the things I like.

However, there seems to be a conflict. They strongly recommend limiting each line to 79 characters, yet they strongly recommend that method and variable names use_underscores_between_words.

On a typical line, where you're nested in a

```
class -> 
    method -> 
        loop -> 
            conditional -> 
                my_var_name += do_some_function(some_parameter, another_parameter)
```

you already have 79 - 16 = 63 characters to work with, and you're wasting 6 on just underscores. So the line above is already too long and it's actually pretty short.

It seems productivity would suffer if I have to count characters so often, or split a rudimentary line like this onto several lines.

I understand that now it says "if your team agrees, use 99", but it seems this should be the standard, or rather that camelCaseVars should be the standard since we like short lines so much.

My issue with coding standards-compliant Python is that I can't seem to write any code without either using cryptic names, or violating the line length or naming convention.  I could post my code here to show you my specific issues, but my example above represents the issue I'm having with my code.

Which ideal is less important? Clear names, short lines, or using_underscores?

**UPDATE:** while no one actually suggested this, I'm getting the feeling that using less descriptive / function and variable names is actually what is tacitly being asked of me.  I know people would say "of course not, just wrap your lines", but in practice, it seems to be a mix of "use very short names" and "wrap lines", but stick to 80.

I think that's what people have done, but I think on the business project level, where productivity is king, teams have just thrown out that rule and jumped to 120. For now, I think I'll just stick to 79 with lots of (imho) ugly line wraps, and feel comforted by the thought of me being able to view 2 files side by side on a small monitor.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better suited to [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) as it doesn't really deal with specific code but rather with principles of programming and coding techniques. From the site's about page: `"Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development."`. I feel your's  is definitely a conceptual question.

Comment: I don't see how *6* characters are an issue. Most of the time using camel case does *not* make the line fit, so you'd have to split the line anyway. I really don't see the problem.

Comment: Why is splitting a function call over multiple lines not desirable? I sometimes argue with myself over how to split elegantly and idiomatically, but I basically never need to go beyond the 80th column.

Comment: @Lix  Oh, Fair enough.  I wasn't after philosophy or taking sides, I'm just after practically writing my lines of code. But you're probably right.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing - I'm not saying this question is bad for [so] - just that you might get some better answers over on Programmers.SE :)

Comment: If this happens often it may be a sign that you need to refactor some of that stuff out into its own functions.  PEP8 also tells us that we should [ignore PEP8 when necessary](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds), so probably you should just stop worrying about being "standards compliant" and just write readable code.

Comment: @roippi sounds reasonable, It's just that this was coming up a whole lot of functions, so I wouldn't want to be breaking the standard "as a rule".

Comment: @tripleee That's a valid point.  I certainly like lists with a few elements to be formatted on separate lines.  But it does seem that a typical function call with a couple basic parameters would be best as one line.  otherwise it feels too much like the old ASM days and calling conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python Zen](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says:

> Flat is better than nested.

Therefore consider decreasing a nesting of your code by code decomposition - make the code less nested by extracting some parts into separate methods or functions. And you'll always have enough horizontal space in your editor.

**Update**

For the nested loops with conditions you can also decrease the nesting level by the decomposition.

For example you can change this code:

```
class MyClass(BaseClass):

    def my_method():
        for item in self.my_collection:
            if item.numeric_property % 2:
                self.my_property = item.other_property + item.age * self.my_coefficient
        self.do_other_stuff()
```

to this one:

```
class MyClass(BaseClass):

    def my_method():
        """People see what happen because of clear names"""
        self.process_my_collection()
        self.do_other_stuff()

    def process_my_collection():
        """People see what happen because of clear names.
        They probably don't even need to read your math from
        process_my_collection_item(item) at all.
        And you make the code more flat as well.
        """
        for item in self.my_collection:
            self.process_my_collection_item(item)

    def process_my_collection_item(item):
        """The most people don't need to read these calculations every time
        since they just know it's working and tested
        but they'd like to work with methods above frequently:
        """
        if not item.numeric_property % 2:
            return
        self.my_property = item.other_property + item.age * self.my_coefficient
```

As you can see I divided one method to a few simple operations and made it less nested.

Comment: That's a good point.   I was trying to be typical in my example.  I mean the class -> method -> loop level is an unavoidable given, but I suppose a conditional could be turned into a simple function.  It seems like performance could suffer though since these are inner loops

Comment: even after your refactoring and adding two new functions, your still at 79 chars!  Oh well, I guess if a lot of libraries are written that way, it must be possible.  I have a feeling cryptic names are the norm though.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal should be to write code that is easy to understand.

*Generally speaking*, adhering to PEP8 gets you a step closer to that goal. If the nature of your code and/or your team is such that camelcase works better, by all means use camelcase.

That being said, if you think it is import to save six characters for what you perceive is a typical line, maybe that is telling you that your typical lines are nested too deep, and there's a better solution than to change naming conventions.

Comment: Ok, I just felt like maybe I was the new guy and everyone was laughing at me for actually trying to follow the manual, or that maybe I was missing something else

Comment: +1.  Personally I think some PEP8's recommendations (like the 80-char limit) are bad, or at best just perpetuate needless conventions.

Comment: My take on the 80 character limit is that 100 is a more practical limit, but I don't know if I've ever seen code that stuck to the 80  character limit where I thought "gee, this would be more readable if the lines were longer". An 80 character limit means that you're forced to answer the question "is this line too long" more often than if you had a larger limit, but that's not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: @BryanOakley yeah, I recently saw a statistic that 95% of github python projects actually do adhere to the 80 char limit.  But somehow I have a feeling they end up with cryptic names which seems worse

Answer (score 1):

Use underscores, it's what everyone expects.

-However- the 79 character limit is one of the more easily set aside recommendations. My team uses pep8 with 119 character lines, but the vast majority of our lines are under 80 characters anyway.

Comment: That would have been my guess.  While I'm quite comfortable with camelCase,  I'm fine with following a convention like that, but it just seemed to conflict with a very strong convention of 79 chars.